# How to make dynamically adding of rows when user reached to the last row of the UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, dynamic

I have a `UITableview` which shows 10 rows currently which is fixed static. Now I want to add a feature into it. I want to add a more 10 rows to the table when user reach to the last row of the `UITableView`. I mean currently I am showing fixed 10 rows in the application.

But now I want to add 10 more rows whenever user reaches to the last row of previous `UITableview`.

Please give me any suggestions or any sample code to achieve my motive. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How would you exactly want to invoke the loading of the additional 10 rows? When a user just scrolls down to see the first 10 that are loaded by default he might not want to load 10 more already.

You may add a "add more" line as the last row of your table. When the user clicks on this one you add 10 more.

(I don't know how one would detect a "bouncing effect" like shifting up the visible rows to indicate that one would like to see more.)

The basic logic would look like this:

1. in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you check if the user clicked on the last line and then invoke your code to add the 10
2. to actually add 10 more lines you have to call `[myTable reloadData]`
3. but before you call you need to increase the returned value of `numberOfRowsInSection` by 10 and make sure that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will correctly return your new lines 11-20

ps if you REALLY want 10 additional rows to be loaded when the user reaches the end of the table you need to invoke the loading of 10 more in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` when it is called for your last line.

Answer (score 15):

It is actually quite simple. What you need to do is implement the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method, which belongs to the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol. This method hits every time a cell is about to be displayed. So, it will let you know when the last cell is about to be displayed. Then you could do something like-

```
– (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *) cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
     if(indexPath.row == [self.array count] - 1) //self.array is the array of items you are displaying
     {
          //If it is the last cell, Add items to your array here & update the table view
     }
}
```

Another (a bit mathematical) option is to implement `UIScrollView` delegate methods (`UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`), namely `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:` or `scrollViewDidScroll:`. These will let you know the y-position of the content the user is viewing. If it is found that the bottom most content is visible, you can add more items.

Answer (score 12):

`uitableview` is derived from `uiscrollview`. To achieve your objective, you need to implement `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`:

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    float endScrolling = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height;
    if (endScrolling >= scrollView.contentSize.height) 
    {
      // your code goes here
    }
}
```

This will detect a "bouncing effect" like shifting up the visible rows to indicate that one would like to see more.

Comment: Clever solution, but I think that detecting you're at the last (or last-x) cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath is better. That way you don't wait until you're past the last cell to load more data.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [categoriesList count];
}
```

Here categoriesList is an array. We can add objects to this array and call reloadData in the tableview.