# UITableView -> How to load additional entry on scroll down?

Tags: ios, uitableview, load

I want to load my data on scroll down for my tableView.

I have a JSON API from where I get my data.
Its a Private Message System. 
Everytime I will get 20 entries, I can select a page (0 to x) get the first to x entries (everytime 20 entries).
So at the moment I have my table and I load a list of 20 entries and show them.

Now I want to have as soon as I reach the last entry it should load the next 20 entries.

I try to read many things about it here on StakcOVerflow and look at a Github Project with this but don't understand it at all.
Can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `willDisplayCell` method of UITableview. For ex, to see whether a row has 'load-more' button if you have one.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170821/how-to-make-dynamically-adding-of-rows-when-user-reached-to-the-last-row-of-the) post.

A [Github](https://github.com/stephenjames/ContinuousTableview) project.

Comment: Your last link no longer works. Do you know where a valid one is?

Comment: @Telthien. The link is removed. will update with some other soon.

Answer (score 3):

you can implement this delegate

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//put data on your array
[tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: This approach is not good because on reloadData, the very same willDisplayCell: will be called and so on and so on.

Comment: willDisplayCell will be called only when new cells will apear , not for visible ones