# auto loading data when scrolling down in ios application

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to do the following in my application:

I got my data from an online server, and I put them in cells, What I need is to auto loading the data when scrolling down, means for example 10 cells are loaded when the application is running, then when I scroll down 10 other cells are dynamically loaded.

Like the following example:

[image]

Thank You per advance,

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12165132/1328096

Answer (score 6):

You can implement this method inside your view controller and get your next record

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

        if (([scrollView contentOffset].y + scrollView.frame.size.height) >= [scrollView contentSize].height){

            // Get new record from here
        }
}
```

This is the simplest way to implement paging. if you want to add Activity indicator at the bottom, you can add it inside the same function.

Answer (score 4):

This automatically loads next fragment of data when user is scrolling near the bottom:

```
#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.contentOffset.y - scrollView.frame.size.height < 60) {
        [self loadRequest];
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you have to subtract scrollview.frame.size.height? I would have just done contentSize.height - contentOffset.y

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

[STableViewController](https://github.com/shiki/STableViewController)

STableViewController is best for "Load more" and "Pull to refresh" both.

Answer (score 0):

For  iOS 6.0, there is a standard control called UIRefreshControl within sdk. [apple doc here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference.html)

and Other here is a step by step Tutorial [give here](http://blog.leahculver.com/2010/12/iphone-pull-to-refresh.html).

Other Open source library available.

1. [EGOTableViewPullRefresh](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh)
2. [PullToRefresh](https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh)
3. [SVPullToRefresh](https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh)
4. [QBRefreshControl](https://github.com/questbeat/QBRefreshControl)
5. [STableViewController](https://github.com/shiki/STableViewController)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Following method for this :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     //put data on your array 
     [tableView reloadData];
}
```

For Better Understand See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170821/how-to-make-dynamically-adding-of-rows-when-user-reached-to-the-last-row-of-the)

You'll also get the Source code from [here](https://github.com/stephenjames/ContinuousTableview)

Hope this will help.